# JQuery Plugin For Html Table Live Search

Tags: jquery, laravel, html-table

I am trying to use plugin of jquery for data-tables but the live search is not appearing because there's some error. The error message is

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchText' of undefined
    at m.fn.init.$.fn.tableSearch (html-table-search.js:12)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (select2.js:27)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
$.fn.tableSearch @ html-table-search.js:12
(anonymous) @ select2.js:27
j @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
J @ jquery.min.js:2"
```

does anyone also encounter this? How can I fix this? Im doing it in laravel

**My main layout**

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>SRI Plugins | </title>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src=" {{{ asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}}"></script> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">         </script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/green.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- jVectorMap -->
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css') }}}" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/custom.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Jquery Ajax -->
    @yield('jquery_ajax_custom')

    <!-- Sweetalert for validation of jquery / ajax fileupload -->
    @yield('sweetalert2')
    @include('live_search_laravel.partials.header') 


  </head>
```

**View for my live search**

```
@extends('layout.default')
@section('content')
<br><br>
<br><br>
<div class="container">
    <h4>Live Search using Laravel</h4>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 pull-right" >

        <p class="pull-right">Click on the zip logo to download the file:<p>

            <a href="/live_search_laravel.zip" download="live-search(laravel).zip">
                <br><br>
                <img border="0" src="/images/ziplogo.png" class="pull-right" alt="AngularJS" width="50" height="42">

            </a>
        </div>



    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="x_panel">

            <div class="x_content">
                <table class="search-table table table-hover">

                    <tr>

                        <th>
                            Original File Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Change File Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            File Extension
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Image
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Category
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Statusx
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach($data as $file)
                    <tr>

                        <td>{{ $file->original_filename}}</td> 
                        <td>{{ $file->rs_filename}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $file->file_extension}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $file->file_extension}}</td>
                        <td>@if($file->category=="1"){{ "Laravel" }}@endif</td>
                        <td>
                            @if($file->status=="0")
                            <form action="/activateImage/{{  $file->id}}" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Activate</button>
                            </form>
                            @else
                            <form action="{{ url('deactivateImage', ['id' => $file->id]) }}" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Deactivate</button>
                            </form>
                            @endif
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>All Activated Images using Foreach</h4>
    @foreach($data as $file)


    @if($file->status=="1")
    <div class ="row">
        <div class ="form-group">
            <img src="/files/images/{{ $file->rs_filename }} "  width ="50px" height ="50px">
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    @endforeach
    <h4>All Images using the index</h4>
    <div class ="row">
        <div class ="form-group">
            <img src="/files/images/{{ $data[0]['rs_filename']}} "  width ="50px" height ="50px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 pull-right">
        <img src="/files/images/{{ $data[1]['rs_filename']}} "  width ="50px" height ="50px">

    </div>
    @stop
    @section('select2_js')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/live_search_laravel/select2.js"></script>

    @stop
```

**JS**

```
/**
    **options to have following keys:
        **searchText: this should hold the value of search text
        **searchPlaceHolder: this should hold the value of search input box placeholder
**/
(function($){
    $.fn.tableSearch = function(options){
        if(!$(this).is('table')){
            return;
        }
        var tableObj = $(this),
            searchText = (options.searchText)?options.searchText:'Search: ',
            searchPlaceHolder = (options.searchPlaceHolder)?options.searchPlaceHolder:'',
            divObj = $('<div style="float:right;">'+searchText+'</div><br /><br />'),
            inputObj = $('<input type="text" placeholder="'+searchPlaceHolder+'" />'),
            caseSensitive = (options.caseSensitive===true)?true:false,
            searchFieldVal = '',
            pattern = '';
        inputObj.off('keyup').on('keyup', function(){
            searchFieldVal = $(this).val();
            pattern = (caseSensitive)?RegExp(searchFieldVal):RegExp(searchFieldVal, 'i');
            tableObj.find('tbody tr').hide().each(function(){
                var currentRow = $(this);
                currentRow.find('td').each(function(){
                    if(pattern.test($(this).html())){
                        currentRow.show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        tableObj.before(divObj.append(inputObj));
        return tableObj;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: where's you javascript code in which you are getting error?

Comment: I edited my post, i put the js

Comment: The error is starting here searchText = (options.searchText)?options.searchText:'Search: ',

Comment: @Angel try `console.log(options)` it seems `options` is `undefined`

Comment: Sir, what if I would like to put some validation like need 3 characters to begin the searching? Like in select2 live search(if you familiar with that)